# How to choose optimal threshold for class probabilities?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

My output of neural network is table of predicted class probabilities for *multi-label classification*:

```
print(probabilities)

|   |      1       |      3       | ... |     8354     |     8356     |     8357     |
|---|--------------|--------------|-----|--------------|--------------|--------------|
| 0 | 2.442745e-05 | 5.952136e-06 | ... | 4.254002e-06 | 1.894523e-05 | 1.033957e-05 |
| 1 | 7.685694e-05 | 3.252202e-06 | ... | 3.617730e-06 | 1.613792e-05 | 7.356643e-06 |
| 2 | 2.296657e-06 | 4.859554e-06 | ... | 9.934525e-06 | 9.244772e-06 | 1.377618e-05 |
| 3 | 5.163169e-04 | 1.044035e-04 | ... | 1.435158e-04 | 2.807420e-04 | 2.346930e-04 |
| 4 | 2.484626e-06 | 2.074290e-06 | ... | 9.958628e-06 | 6.002510e-06 | 8.434519e-06 |
| 5 | 1.297477e-03 | 2.211737e-04 | ... | 1.881772e-04 | 3.171079e-04 | 3.228884e-04 |
```

I converted it to class labels using a threshold (***0.2***) for measuring accuraccy of my prediction:

```
predictions = (probabilities > 0.2).astype(np.int)
print(predictions)

|   | 1 | 3 | ... | 8354 | 8356 | 8357 |
|---|---|---|-----|------|------|------|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

Also I have a test set:

```
print(Y_test)

|   | 1 | 3 | ... | 8354 | 8356 | 8357 |
|---|---|---|-----|------|------|------|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | ... |    0 |    0 |    0 |
```

**Question:** How to build an algorithm in Python that will choose the optimal threshold that maximize `roc_auc_score(average = 'micro')` or another metrics?

Maybe it is possible to build manual function in Python that optimize threshold, depending on the accuracy metric.

Comment: Might want to take a look at [`roc_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html). This will help you adjust your threshold. There's no right/wrong threshold. It depends on your business's tolerance for false positives.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, ok, but also I want manually change metric of accuraccy(e.g. `accuracy_score`, `f1_score`). So maybe it is possible to build manual function in Python that optimize threshold

Comment: Gotcha, in that case, my best answer for you is to build a function that takes a threshold argument and uses your NN to generate the probabilities instead of the class values and then determine the class using the threshold. Then, run a grid search over your threshold array to find the best threshold.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr, ok. However, how to implement grid search to find the best threshold in Python?

Comment: What are the columns you are showing? Do you have 8357 *classes*? And is the class membership unique (each sample can belong only  to one class) or you are in a multi-label context (samples can belong to more than one class)?

Comment: @desertnaut, multi-label classifictaion

Comment: Please edit & update your post to explicitly include this info!

Comment: @desertnaut, updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your groundtruth labels are `Y_test` and predictions are `predictions`.

Optimizing `roc_auc_score(average = 'micro')` according to a prediction `threshold` does not seem to make sense as AUCs are computed based on how predictions are ranked and therefore need `predictions` as float values in `[0,1]`.

Therefore, I will discuss `accuracy_score`.

You could use [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html):

```
import scipy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def thr_to_accuracy(thr, Y_test, predictions):
   return -accuracy_score(Y_test, np.array(predictions>thr, dtype=np.int))

best_thr = scipy.optimize.fmin(thr_to_accuracy, args=(Y_test, predictions), x0=0.5)
```

Comment: I have the next error: `TypeError: fmin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial_guess'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just corrected the keyword argument to `x0`.

Comment: `TypeError: thr_to_accuracy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'thr'`

Comment: Your method also need `predictions` as probabilities between 0,1. Only then it will work.

Comment: @syltruong, `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`

Comment: @VivekKumar in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), it seems like `accuracy_score` takes labels only as input.

Comment: @syltruong, I haven't not quite understood the output of this function: 
        `Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 16
         Function evaluations: 42`

Comment: if I print `best_thr` value i will gain the next result:                                                                                                                 `array([1.075])`

Comment: So `fmin` minimises the objective function. But here our goal is maximize the accuracy. I just changed the function output to `-accuracy_score`. Sorry for the confusion. Hope it works now.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `accuracy_score` takes discrete labels. I was talking about the from `predictions` param that you are sending to `thr_to_accuracy`. That needs to be probabilities, right?

Comment: @VivekKumar, yes indeed. The threshold is being applied to the prediction probabilities.

Comment: But in your post you say that roc_auc require probabilities between 0,1 so you suggest accuracy. But then in accuracy alos you use probabilities between 0,1 . So my question was why not do this optimisation on roc_auc?

Comment: Because in roc_auc there would be no threshold to optimize on

Comment: I think this is a suboptimal solution to the problem as fmin stops the optimization at the first local minimum if finds. In my case, it stopped at best_thr=0.525 while simply setting best_thr=0.1 gives a higher accuracy score.

Answer (score 5):

According to @cangrejo's answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/310956/194535, suppose the original output probability of your model is the vector v, and then you can define the prior distribution:

π=(1/θ1, 1/θ2,..., 1/θN), for θi∈(0,1) and Σθi = 1, where N is the total number of labeled classes, i is the class index.

Take v' = v⊙π as the new output probability of your model, where ⊙ denotes an element-wise product.

Now, your question can be reformulate to this: Finding the π which optimize the metrics you have specified (eg. roc_auc_score) from the new output probability model. Once you find it, the θs (θ1, θ2, ..., θN) is your optimal threshold for each classes.

The Code part:

---

1. Create a `proxyModel` class which takes your original model object as an argument and return a `proxyModel` object. When you called `predict_proba()` through the `proxyModel` object, it will calculate new probability automatically based on the threshold you specified:

   ```
   class proxyModel():
       def __init__(self, origin_model):
           self.origin_model = origin_model

       def predict_proba(self, x, threshold_list=None):
           # get origin probability
           ori_proba = self.origin_model.predict_proba(x)

           # set default threshold
           if threshold_list is None:
               threshold_list = np.full(ori_proba[0].shape, 1)

           # get the output shape of threshold_list
           output_shape = np.array(threshold_list).shape

           # element-wise divide by the threshold of each classes
           new_proba = np.divide(ori_proba, threshold_list)

           # calculate the norm (sum of new probability of each classes)
           norm = np.linalg.norm(new_proba, ord=1, axis=1)

           # reshape the norm
           norm = np.broadcast_to(np.array([norm]).T, (norm.shape[0],output_shape[0]))

           # renormalize the new probability
           new_proba = np.divide(new_proba, norm)

           return new_proba

       def predict(self, x, threshold_list=None):
           return np.argmax(self.predict_proba(x, threshold_list), axis=1)
   ```
2. Implement a score function:

   ```
   def scoreFunc(model, X, y_true, threshold_list):
       y_pred = model.predict(X, threshold_list=threshold_list)
       y_pred_proba = model.predict_proba(X, threshold_list=threshold_list)

       ###### metrics ######
       from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
       from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
       from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
       from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

       accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
       roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred_proba, average='macro')
       pr_auc = average_precision_score(y_true, y_pred_proba, average='macro')
       f1_value = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')

       return accuracy, roc_auc, pr_auc, f1_value
   ```
3. Define `weighted_score_with_threshold()` function, which takes the threshold as input and return weighted score:

   ```
   def weighted_score_with_threshold(threshold, model, X_test, Y_test, metrics='accuracy', delta=5e-5):
       # if the sum of thresholds were not between 1+delta and 1-delta, 
       # return infinity (just for reduce the search space of the minimizaiton algorithm, 
       # because the sum of thresholds should be as close to 1 as possible).
       threshold_sum = np.sum(threshold)

       if threshold_sum > 1+delta:
           return np.inf

       if threshold_sum < 1-delta:
           return np.inf

       # to avoid objective function jump into nan solution
       if np.isnan(threshold_sum):
           print("threshold_sum is nan")
           return np.inf

       # renormalize: the sum of threshold should be 1
       normalized_threshold = threshold/threshold_sum

       # calculate scores based on thresholds
       # suppose it'll return 4 scores in a tuple: (accuracy, roc_auc, pr_auc, f1)
       scores = scoreFunc(model, X_test, Y_test, threshold_list=normalized_threshold)    

       scores = np.array(scores)
       weight = np.array([1,1,1,1])

       # Give the metric you want to maximize a bigger weight:
       if metrics == 'accuracy':
           weight = np.array([10,1,1,1])
       elif metrics == 'roc_auc':
           weight = np.array([1,10,1,1])
       elif metrics == 'pr_auc':
           weight = np.array([1,1,10,1])
       elif metrics == 'f1':
           weight = np.array([1,1,1,10])
       elif 'all':
           weight = np.array([1,1,1,1])

       # return negatitive weighted sum (because you want to maximize the sum, 
       # it's equivalent to minimize the negative sum)
       return -np.dot(weight, scores)
   ```
4. Use optimize algorithm `differential_evolution()` (better then fmin) to find the optimal threshold:

   ```
   from scipy import optimize

   output_class_num = Y_test.shape[1]
   bounds = optimize.Bounds([1e-5]*output_class_num,[1]*output_class_num)

   pmodel = proxyModel(model)

   result = optimize.differential_evolution(weighted_score_with_threshold, bounds, args=(pmodel, X_test, Y_test, 'accuracy'))

   # calculate threshold
   threshold = result.x/np.sum(result.x)

   # print the optimized score
   print(scoreFunc(model, X_test, Y_test, threshold_list=threshold))
   ```

Comment: This is the best soln.  I've implemented similar before - although included a few 'extra flares': a) on combining/ weighting the scores, I indexed the corrected AIC (penalised by # parameters) and a 'ks-ratio' (kolmogorov s. test statistic as % of the critical value, e.g. 5% one-sided) - the lower the ks-ratio, obviously the more favourable in terms of goodness of tail-fit.  The indexed AIC(c) and KS-ratio thus varied between 0-1, and the weights were designed to attribute bias towards larger thresholds (the purpose, in my case, was to determine Increased Limit Factors using a spliced cdf...)

Comment: An uninformed prior re: weights was thus: (n-i)/n  where i represented the (asc.) ordered rank of each observation in the n total observed (each of which were assumed to be a plausible splicing pt.).  Concluding remarks: the AIC(c) was useful in determining a tuple defining, in turn, an optimal distribution (out of tens/hundreds of possible candidate models), & splicing pt.  The AIC(c) lends itself easily to a Kullback-Leibler 1-a - ile "model confidence set" - using bootstrap simulation.  Whilst ILFs need not necessitate, an additional requirement was the need for Micollis consistency.... PTO

Comment: ...and this is defined as the need for the resulting distribution to preserve downward concavity (2nd derivate < 0) - i.e. increasing at a decreasing rate of increase (just as any distribution should! :).  Final checks/refinements included checking differentiability / discontinuity at the cross over from empirical to parametric (mle based solutions lose several degrees /parameters, rather, in making use of this assumption to solve multiple systems/equations in deriving the optimal splicing pt. as loglikelihood function.... anyways...that's all I have to say on this subject!! :) ciao

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do so is to put a logistic regression on top of your new dataset. It will multiply every probability by a certain constant and thus will provide an automatic threshold on the output (with the LR you just need to predict the class not the probabilities)

You need to train this by subdividing the Test set in two and use one part to train the LR after predicting the output with the NN.

This is not the only way to do it, but it works fine for me everytime.

we have X_train_nn,X_valid_nn,X_test_NN and we subdivide X_test_NN in X_train_LR, X_test_LR (or do a Stratified Kfold as you wish)
here is a sample of the code

```
X_train = NN.predict_proba(X_train_LR)
X_test = NN.predict_proba(X_test_LR)
logistic = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1.0, penalty = 'l2')
logistic.fit(X_train,Y_train)
logistic.score(X_test,Y_test)
```

You condider you output as a new dataset and train a LR on this new dataset.

Comment: I have tried to use a logistic regression, but I have a dataset with approximatelly 8k classes. So logistic works to slow in these conditions. Neural network is one of the best solution in huge multi-label classifiction

Comment: don't replace the NN, put a LR on top of it

Comment: clear, sorry for misunderstanding. But unfortunately I do not quite understand how to implement it. Can you provide sample of code?