# what are different approaches for thresholding on a segmented image other than choosing max probability class label

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, image-segmentation, image-thresholding

I am trying to segment satellite image into 2 classes to extract building footprints from background. I am using binary crossentropy and sigmoid activation. I use max probability value(output of CNN) to assign class label. Is there a better approach than that(I am not getting the shape of segmented buildings right).

I came across this answer for optimal thresholding
[How to choose optimal threshold for class probabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093388/how-to-choose-optimal-threshold-for-class-probabilities)
which approach is best for two class segmentation?

```py
import numpy
pred = model.predict(test_X)
pred = numpy.argmax(pred, axis = 2)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want, Do you wish to improve the **precision** or the **recall**, if both classes are of equal importance to you, you might want to plot **f1_score** as a function of the **probabiliy_threshold** and choose the threshold that maximizes f1.

Comment: @Benjamin Breton, I am interested in one class only(buildings) and not background